# How can i translate those list filters to db queries?

Tags: django

**edit:**

To prevent everyone from reading too much: The problem is that i do not understand what

```
Q(tag_rep__tag=tag.id)
```

really does for this model:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    tag_rep=generic.GenericRelation(TaggedItem)
```

Most probably tag_rep__tag does return a list of tags, not a single tag. So i can't just do the query like i did it. How can i compare tag_rep__tag to find out if it

1. contains any of a list of tags
2. contains all of a list of tags

---

I'm trying to build a queryset based tagfilter for items that have tagging tags. I allready succeeded with the creation of the filters, but they are based on pythons `filter` and return a list:

```
class TagFilter(object):

    def __init__(self,any_tags,avoid_tags,all_tags):
         # all tags as tag instances
         self.any_tags = any_tags
         self.avoid_tags = avoid_tags
         self.all_tags = all_tags

    def seek_any_tags(self, item):
        for tag in self.any_tags:
            if tag in item.tags:
               return True
        return False

    def items_with_any_tags(self,items):
        return filter(self.seek_any_tags,items)
```

This worked pretty well, but now i need a queryset in return to pass into a formset. So the current method is not working anymore, as it returns a list. To be able to access the tags of my model i did this:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from tagging.models import TaggedItem

class Item(models.Model):

    # some_fields here

    tag_rep = generic.GenericRelation(TaggedItem)
```

The filter `seek_any_tags` was the only one i could allready rebuild in form of a database query. After reading some SO posts and doing a lot of googling i came up with this solution:

```
def seek_any_tags_qs(self,items):

    if self.any_tags!=None:
        q = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(tag_rep__tag=tag.id) for tag in self.any_tags])
        items = items.filter(q)

    return items
```

Quite nice, and yes, i'm a bit proud about it. But now there are two more filters i want to build: `avoid_any_tags` and `seek_all_tags`. I tried to do them in the same way i did the `seek_any_tags` filter:

```
def avoid_any_tags_qs(self,items):

    if self.avoid_tags != None:
        q = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(tag_rep__tag=tag.id) for tag in self.avoid_tags])
        items = items.exclude(q)

    return items


def seek_all_tags_qs(self,items):

    if self.all_tags != None:
        q = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [Q(_tags__contains=tag.name) for tag in self.seek_tags])
        items.filter(q)

    return items
```

`avoid_any_tags` should exclude every item that has any of the tags in avoid_tags. The last one, `seek_all_tags`, should only return items that have all of the tags in all_tags.

But `avoid_any_tags` doesn't work as exected. It only excludes elements that have tags in avoid_tags and none else. If an item has any tag that is not in avoid_tags it is not excluded. Why not?

Comment: Are these filters to be used on seperate queryset objects? Or are you passing a single one through them and stacking up filters and excludes?

Comment: I'm stacking them up, but i think that's not the problem. I checked that a few times in different orders. Update will be there in two minutes, i probably found the crux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a fully appropriate query (from your examples):

```
Q(tag_rep__tag=tag.id)
```

I am assuming you are following close to the [examples listed here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/), and that the tag field of that TaggedItem is a slug (string) field? So right off the bat, filtering where the id is equal to the slugfield does not seem right. Also, you are correct that your GenericRelation represents a list (or a queryset for that matter). Its a reverse reference back to the TaggedItem specifying its foreignkey field. So you would be able to do: `Item.tag_rep.all()`

There is so much extra information in your question that its a bit hard to follow, so I am just going to ignore most of that and address your summary at the top.

```
# Any of a list of strings*
any_tags = ['foo', 'bar']
Item.objects.filter(tag_rep__tag__in=any_tags)
```

As for the "has all tags in given tag list", maybe there is a really complex django query based way to do this, but here is an approach with the intermediate steps being on the client side:

```
# items having all tags in a given list of tags
from collections import defaultdict

tag_vals = Item.objects.all().values_list('id', 'tags__tag').distinct()
# produces result like:  `[(1, u'bdfl'), (1, u'boom'), (2, u'bar'), ...)`

all_tags = set(['boom', 'fizz'])

tag_groups = defaultdict(set)
for id_, tag in tag_vals:
    tag_groups[id_].add(tag)
# produces tag_groups like `{1: set([u'fizz', u'foo', u'boom']), ...}`

item_ids = [id_ for id_,tags in d.iteritems() if tags.issubset(all_tags)]
Item.objects.filter(id__in=item_ids)
```

In this last example, it would match situations where an Item has tags `['a,'b']` and the all_tags is `['a','b',c']`, but it would not match situations where the Item has more tags than are in all_tags, but the ones it has do match. To have it match either way, you would have to modify that item_ids filter:

```
item_ids = [id_ for id_,tags in d.iteritems() if \
                tags.issubset(all_tags) or tags.issuperset(all_tags)]
Item.objects.filter(id__in=item_ids)
```

Comment: `it would not match situations where the Item has more tags than are in all_tags, but the ones it has do match` - This is exactly what happened with the avoid query. Problem with your solution still is that it returns a list instead of a queryset. But thanks for trying to clarify things a bit.

Comment: @marue: What are you talking about? Both of my examples result in a queryset. I was clear in saying that the approach uses a little bit of client side processing, but the final query is a queryset. I think you misread my addition at the end. It was a modified version of the client side filter but you still then run the query with it. I just updated the example to make it more clear.

Comment: Oh man, that's the result of asking complex questions: You get complex answers (which you then don't understand)... Sorry for that, i was so stuck in finding a solution that worked that i didn't really get to the point of your answer. I'll post my solution shortly (it works now), but right now will dive into understanding your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

To make it short, this is the code that works:

```
# does the item have any of the seek tags?
has_seek_tags = Q(tags__id__in=self.seek_tags)
items = items.filter(has_seek_tags).distinct()

# does the item have any of the avoid tags?    
has_avoid_tags= Q(tags__id__in=self.avoid_tags)
items = items.exclude(has_avoid_tags).distinct()

# now apply the queries
for tag_id in self.all_tags:
    items = items.filter(has_avoid_tags)
```

What i still do not understand is, why items.filter in the for loop is not the same as this:

```
q = reduce(lambda x,y: x&y, [Q(tags__id__exact=tag_id) for tag_id in self.all_tags)
items = items.filter(q)
```

But maybe that's a question on it's own.

Comment: The Q objects are not neccessary in your first set of examples. You are only doing one statement. It can be expressed directly without a Q. And for your reduce, it should be a logical OR, not an AND. Or maybe I dont understand what youbare trying to express with the reduce.

Comment: You are absolutely right with the Q objects. Look like i fell in love with them too much, time to kick them out. With the second filter i'm pretty sure it is messed up all the way. Thanks for your efforts.